# How do I perform a bootstrap in R and estimate the variance?

Tags: r

The dataset, "male.wt" is a collection of 100 weights of male taxi patrons. Use bootstrap sampling to estimate the variance for the population of males who use taxis.

I am trying to use the boot() function in R and I am just completely confused.
Here is the data set that was given to me to do this problem.

```
malewt = structure(list(x = c(184.291514203183, 238.183299307855, 217.544606414151, 
233.931926116624, 229.12042611005, 243.881689583996, 259.230802242781, 
217.939619221934, 137.636923032685, 170.379447345948, 195.852641733122, 
185.832690963969, 186.676714564328, 215.711426139253, 186.413495533494, 
237.83223009147, 180.124153998503, 215.393108191779, 188.846039074142, 
142.373198101437, 233.234630310378, 186.141325709762, 220.062112044187, 
213.851199681057, 148.622198219149, 197.438771523918, 206.920961557603, 
190.874857845699, 217.889075914836, 152.318099234166, 218.089620221194, 
196.736930479919, 235.122424359223, 217.446826955801, 201.352404389309, 
216.290374765672, 173.85609629461, 215.961826427613, 213.87732008193, 
177.952521505061, 132.734879010504, 221.707886490889, 224.336488758995, 
218.604034088911, 228.157844234374, 196.544661577149, 228.787736646279, 
237.009125179319, 194.73342863066, 190.569523115323, 192.198491573128, 
204.589742888237, 198.662802876867, 195.238634847898, 201.834508205684, 
220.989134791548, 180.006492709174, 168.199898332071, 250.705048451896, 
209.824701073225, 212.36145906497, 205.250728119598, 196.572466206237, 
186.818746613236, 138.493748904934, 193.572713536688, 171.605082170236, 
243.803356964054, 188.768040728907, 201.408088256783, 196.23847341016, 
202.686141019735, 167.25735383257, 171.907526464761, 224.396425425799, 
183.494470842407, 220.15969728649, 143.164453849305, 152.539942653094, 
198.52004650272, 185.145815429412, 206.741840856439, 259.866591064748, 
135.212011256414, 164.2297511973, 200.623731663392, 199.599177980586, 
175.970651370212, 197.304554981825, 189.116019204125, 198.630618004183, 
185.096675814379, 203.780160863916, 174.584831373708, 150.483001599829, 
223.78078870159, 170.772181294322, 218.770812392057, 151.645084212409, 
210.350813872005)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L
))
```

Comment: The data set cannot be accessed without a tlu.edu login. Are you able to make it available or can you edit the question to include a sample of the data using dput()? Please also share what you've tried so far, or clarify what is confusing. Is the issue in interpreting the output of boot() or in working out the syntax to use the function?

Comment: I made the file into an html so hopefully you can access it here (file:///Users/bradenjenschke/Desktop/malewt%20(1).htm)

Comment: My main issue is the syntax really and just knowing what to do. I've never done a bootstrapping example and everything online is just confusing.

Comment: That file is on your personal computer, and can only be opened locally. Please try this in R: import the data into a data frame, then run the dput on the object. You can copy the output and paste it into your original question (click edit at the end of the question). Others will be able to copy from your question and recreate the object in their own IDE.

Comment: Thank you and I updated it

Answer (score 3):

Very ambiguous question. Here is how to plot a histogram of the bootstrap estimator of the variance:

```r
library(purrr)
boots <- 100
data <- structure(list(x = c(184.291514203183, 238.183299307855, 217.544606414151, 233.931926116624, 229.12042611005, 243.881689583996, 259.230802242781, 217.939619221934, 137.636923032685, 170.379447345948, 195.852641733122, 185.832690963969, 186.676714564328, 215.711426139253, 186.413495533494, 237.83223009147, 180.124153998503, 215.393108191779, 188.846039074142, 142.373198101437, 233.234630310378, 186.141325709762, 220.062112044187, 213.851199681057, 148.622198219149, 197.438771523918, 206.920961557603, 190.874857845699, 217.889075914836, 152.318099234166, 218.089620221194, 196.736930479919, 235.122424359223, 217.446826955801, 201.352404389309, 216.290374765672, 173.85609629461, 215.961826427613, 213.87732008193, 177.952521505061, 132.734879010504, 221.707886490889, 224.336488758995, 218.604034088911, 228.157844234374, 196.544661577149, 228.787736646279, 237.009125179319, 194.73342863066, 190.569523115323, 192.198491573128, 204.589742888237, 198.662802876867, 195.238634847898, 201.834508205684, 220.989134791548, 180.006492709174, 168.199898332071, 250.705048451896, 209.824701073225, 212.36145906497, 205.250728119598, 196.572466206237, 186.818746613236, 138.493748904934, 193.572713536688, 171.605082170236, 243.803356964054, 188.768040728907, 201.408088256783, 196.23847341016, 202.686141019735, 167.25735383257, 171.907526464761, 224.396425425799, 183.494470842407, 220.15969728649, 143.164453849305, 152.539942653094, 198.52004650272, 185.145815429412, 206.741840856439, 259.866591064748, 135.212011256414, 164.2297511973, 200.623731663392, 199.599177980586, 175.970651370212, 197.304554981825, 189.116019204125, 198.630618004183, 185.096675814379, 203.780160863916, 174.584831373708, 150.483001599829, 223.78078870159, 170.772181294322, 218.770812392057, 151.645084212409, 210.350813872005)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L ))
map(seq_len(boots),
    ~ data$x[sample.int(length(data$x), length(data$x), T)]
) %>% 
    map_dbl(var) %>% 
    hist()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you for this help it gives me a little understanding for how the function works

Comment: @Simon I am not really using the `boot` function; it is very easy to produce bs samples which I do with the `purrr::map` function, then I calculate the statistic (variance in this case) with `purrr::map_dbl` which returns a vector of variances (in this case); one per bs sample.

Answer (score 1):

Here is  solution with base package `boot`. In the case of the variance it's very easy to bootstrap it.

1. Create a function `bootvar` to compute each resampled variance;
2. the function **must have the data and indices as 1st and 2nd arguments**. The arguments must be these and by this order, the indices vector is what gives the resampling from the data. It's a vector created automatically for the user by `boot`;
3. in the function extract the sample given by the indices vector (`i` below);
4. compute and return the statistic of interest, `var`.

I wrote the function in two code lines in order to make it more clear.

```r
library(boot)

set.seed(2022)

bootvar <- function(data, i) {
  y <- data$x[i]
  var(y)
}
b <- boot(malewt, bootvar, R = 5000)
b
#> 
#> ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#> 
#> 
#> Call:
#> boot(data = malewt, statistic = bootvar, R = 5000)
#> 
#> 
#> Bootstrap Statistics :
#>     original    bias    std. error
#> t1* 792.2551 -7.657891    106.0901

# bootstrapped variance
mean(b$t)
#> [1] 784.5972

hist(b$t)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

It is also possible to write the bootstrap function so that it takes a vector as its first argument, not a data.frame like above. The call to `boot` is then adapted accordingly. The results are exactly the same as long as the pseudo-RNG seed is set to the same value (in this case `2022`).

```r
library(boot)

set.seed(2022)

bootvar_x <- function(x, i) {
  y <- x[i]
  var(y)
}
bx <- boot(malewt$x, bootvar_x, R = 5000)
bx
#> 
#> ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#> 
#> 
#> Call:
#> boot(data = malewt$x, statistic = bootvar_x, R = 5000)
#> 
#> 
#> Bootstrap Statistics :
#>     original    bias    std. error
#> t1* 792.2551 -7.657891    106.0901

mean(bx$t)
#> [1] 784.5972

hist(bx$t)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>